# problems with Firefox getElementById

Tags: javascript, image, getelementbyid, src

I'm using javascript code to insert scr attribute and display picture. with  chrome it works fine, but doesn't pass the value then I'm using Firefox. I tried to delete cache of Firefox but nothing seems to change. there is the problem

```
var M=document.getElementById('pristatomiesi_akordai');
var N=M.getElementsByTagName('Span')[0].innerHTML; 

if (N=="C") {
    document.getElementById('paveikslelis1').src = "/catalog/Akordai/C/C.JPG";
}
```

Comment: Works for me in both, Chrome and FF: https://jsfiddle.net/tsgst9cb/

Comment: What does it say, when you press F12?

Comment: doest show any error at all

Comment: @StoviRyžasStotelėje, Can you create a *fiddle* by generating the error, it will help us to solve the issue.

Comment: What part is not working?  Could it be that getElementsByTagName('Span') is the problem?  Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: <div id="pristatomiesi_akordai"><span>C</span></div>
    <hr>
    <div>Dainoje naudojami akordai: </div>
    <div id="img_place"><img id="paveikslelis1" ></div>

Comment: I ve tested your html code and an error has been showed because your code doesn't have the span tag.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the InnerHTML by textContent , because textContent retrieves only text nodes:

```
var M = document.getElementById('pristatomiesi_akordai');
var N = M.querySelector('span').textContent;

if (N.toLowerCase() == "c") {
    document.getElementById('paveikslelis1').src = "/catalog/Akordai/C/C.JPG";
}
```